# How can I keep visual studio code from trashing my jsx code?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

I've been working on a simple crud app using reactjs.

Here's a snippet of code

`enter code here`render() {
            return ( 
           
                 Products Manager    <
                AddProduct onAdd = { this.onAdd }
                /> {
                this.state.products.map(product => {
                    return ( <
                        ProductItem key = { product.name } {...product }
                        onDelete = { this.onDelete }
                        onEditSubmit = { this.onEditSubmit }
                        />
                    );
                })
            } 
        );

Looks fine, nothing wrong there. However if I save this, VS Code does the following: tags separated from their angle brackets, etc. My questions is simple-how do I keep VS Code from trashing my code? 
   `enter code here`
render() {
            return ( <
                div className = "App" >
                <
                 h1 > Products Manager < /h1>   <
                AddProduct onAdd = { this.onAdd }
                is.state.products.map(product => {
                    return ( <
                        ProductItem key = { product.name } {...product }
                        onDelete = { this.onDelete }
                        onEditSubmit = { this.onEditSubmit }
                        />
                    );
                })
            } < /div>
        );

Comment: VSCode doesn't auto format code by default. You've either installed a plugin that's doing this, or you've manually turned on Format on Save/Paste.

Comment: Incorrect. VSCode ships with the Javascript Language Service, which adds editor features making authoring JavaScript easy right out-of-the-box. http://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript

Comment: @Trent no, vscode doesn't **auto format** code by default

Comment: It does not auto format the code automatically, but it does indeed ship with the ability to format Javascript sytnax.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have an extension installed that is auto formatting your text. `Prettier` is one of the most popular ones. VSCode to my knowledge does not autoformat your code out of the box.

Comment: VSCode ships with the Javascript Language Service, which adds editor features making authoring JavaScript easy right out-of-the-box. You can learn more about it here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript

Comment: I don't think that's it. Though you are correct in that I'm missing a bracket. the below code is correct(at least vs code says so). And yet vs code mangles this code as well. import React, { Component } from "react";

class Player extends React.Component {


    render() {
        return ( <div> Player </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Player;

Answer (score 0):

It seems like two issues may be contributing towards your issue. Your code is invalid, which might be preventing your formatter from working correctly.

First we can clean up your code so that it is valid Javascript. Two issues exist:

1. You're missing a closing brace for your render function.
2. Adjacent JSX elements must be assigned keys or wrapped in a [React Fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html).

Here's what the valid Javascript looks like after fixing these issue:

```
render() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      Products Manager
      <AddProduct onAdd={this.onAdd} />
      {this.state.products.map(product => {
        return (
          <ProductItem
            key={product.name}
            {...product}
            onDelete={this.onDelete}
            onEditSubmit={this.onEditSubmit}
          />
        );
      })}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

> VSCode has a built in [Javascript Language Service](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/JavaScript-Language-Service-in-Visual-Studio) which allows
>   the editor to support Javascript features out-of-the-box. [Learn more
>   here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript).

Comment: Invalid code? I followed the tutorial and the app works-I don't have a problem with app not workin. I do have a problem with the angles detached from tags and vs code red squiggles everywhere.

Comment: Red squiggles indicate syntax errors. Text and adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag or returned as an array of renderable elements.